# Count all tables in one instance in kdb

Tags: kdb

I would like to count all tables in the same instance.
I have not used kdb for a while and I forgot how to make this work.
This is what I got:

```
tablelist:tables[]
{select count i from x} each tablelist
```

but I got a type error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

```
count each `. tables[]
```

Comment: thanks! do you know whats wrong with my function though?

Comment: could be a range of thing of course. are your tables are on disk? splayed or partitioned?

Comment: it is on disk yeah. partitioned

Comment: do u know how i can query that way

Comment: sorry for the delay. did you find out what was happening? it's pretty hard to know, and debug through this platform, but to try and find the issue run {.Q.cn `. x} each tables[]. Which one does it break on? Are there unknowns in that table's date partitions?

Answer (score 3):

Your statement doesn't contain a trailing semi colon `;` at the end of the first line which will cause an error in an IDE like qpad (assuming you are running it as written).

If not running from an IDE I would check my hdb for any possible missing data and run some sanity checks (i.e can I select from each of my tables normally, do types match across partitions, i is a virtual column representing row count so issues with non-conforming types in your other columns is probably not a cause but investigating may yield the right answer)

One way to achieve what you're trying is (using dummy data):

`q){flip select counts:count i,tab:1#x from x}each tablelist:tables[]`

```
 counts tab
 -------------
 5469   depth
 3150   quotes
 3005   trades
```

Here I select the count for each table, but also add on the name of the table, flip each result into a dictionary, which results in a list of dictionaries of conforming types and key names which is in fact a table, hence my result. In this way you have a nice way to track what you're actually counting.

Answer (score 2):

Each select query you run is returning a table in the form:

```
x
-
3
```

It would be better to use exec as opposed to select to simply return the value of the count e.g:

```
q){exec count i from x} each tables[]
3 2
```

Your current method would be attempting to return a list of tables: e.g:

```
q){select count i from x} each tables[]
+(,`x)!,,3
+(,`x)!,,2
```

However, the type error makes me think there may be an issue with your tables as this should not error for in-memory tables.

Answer (score 1):

I am using 3.6 2018.05.17 and your expression worked for me. I then change the select to an exec to return just a list of counts.

q){exec count i from x} each tables[]

Answer (score 0):

Below code helps us get the count of each table along with tablename.

```
q)flip (`table;`msgcount)! flip {x, count value x}@'tables[]
```

To get only the count and not the tablename along with it.

```
q){count value x}@'tables[]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
q) tables[]!(count value@)each tables[]
heartbeat| 0
logmsg   | 0
packets  | 0
quote    | 206889
quote_iex| 0
trade    | 43309
trade_iex| 0
```

you can even save some typing by doing

```
t!(count value@)each t:tables[]
```